# Assign random color to a vertex inside grey scale range

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to assign a random greyscale color value to a vertex of a mesh.

By using cmds.polyColorPerVertex(rgb=()) I can assign any specific color to a vertex but I can't seem to figure out how to randomize that color value yet lock it into a grayscale range.

In the end a need each time for a vert to be of a different greyscale value.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmds.polyColorPerVertex()` takes an `rgb` tuple in the form `(r, g, b`), where each element should be a `float` in the range `[0, 1]`.

"Greyscale", in this context, just means that `r == g == b`.

Accordingly, we can just use Python's random number generators to achieve this:

```
brightness = np.random.rand() # generates a random float in the range [0, 1]
rgb = (brightness, brightness, brightness)

cmds.polyColorPerVertex(rgb=rgb)
```

Comment: ```brightness = random.uniform(0.1, 1.0)
    rgb = (brightness, brightness, brightness)
    cmds.polyColorPerVertex (rgb=rgb)``` I got it to work with this. Thank you!